# Logic behind Codejam APAC practice round "Not so Random"

Tags: algorithm

So the problem I am referencing can be found here: [Problem C "Not So Random"](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/5254486/dashboard#s=p2)

Now I am having difficulty understanding what the problem is even asking. More specifically, The testcase 1 seems explained properly, but for sample case 2, I don't understand how the value of 5*0.72 was derived.

```
(5&5) -> 5 with 0.1 probability
(5|5) -> 5 with 0.5 probability
(5^5) -> 0 with 0.4 probability
```

that would be the result from machine one. Now, what I don't understand is how the probabilities interact going into machine 2. What is the input for machine 2 being considered? If we consider all three cases with and, or, and xor, then how was 0.72 calculated as the probability of output=5 from machine 2?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your observations, the input for machine 2 is

- 5 with probability 0.6
- 0 with probability 0.4

The other fixed parameter **K** is the same for all the machines, so it is 5 for machine 2 as well.

This leaves us with the following six scenarios about what operation will run on machine 2:

- `5&5=5` with probability 0.6*0.1
- `5|5=5` with probability 0.6*0.5
- `5^5=0` with probability 0.6*0.4
- `0&5=0` with probability 0.4*0.1
- `0|5=5` with probability 0.4*0.5
- `0^5=5` with probability 0.4*0.4

Which gives the distribution that was described in the example: 0 with probability 0.28, and 5 with probability 0.72.

Answer (score 0):

The output of machine 1 is the input to machine 2, so the input to machine 2 is 0 with probability 0.4 and 5 with probability 0.6.

As we've already seen, when the length input to a machine is 5, the output probabilities are 0.4/0.6

Similarly, it should be easy to see that on input 0, the probabilities are 0.1 and 0.9 (either OR or XOR).

So the probability of the concatenated output being 5 is 0.9*0.4 + 0.6*0.6.